# Blazemeter is not replacing JMeter property

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have a JMeter script where I've defined some variables using the config element "User Defined Variables"

[image]

and locally when I use `${host}` for instance in a request it works fine. I uploaded this script to Blazemeter and enabled overriding of properties:

[image]

However when I run the test in Blazemeter the new host value is not being replaced at all. Am I doing something wrong here or am I misreading how this feature is supposed to work in Blazemeter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the variables in the User Defined Variable components, you can access them with `${VariableName}` as they act as [JMeter variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P).

When you define variables in Blazemeter they act as JMeter properties. You can access the [JMeter properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) with `${__P(PropertyName,)}`. You cannot use `${VariableName}` to access the. JMeter properties.

e.g `${__P(host,)}` in your case

You can continue to use the existing script by reading the properties and assigning them to the existing JMeter variable in the User Defined Variables component

[image]

You can set a default value to the property `${__P(host,defaultHost)}`. The script will continue to run on the local environment and Blazemeter.

References :
[JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#introduction)
[User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see where you "define" variables, to wit I see the names, not the values.

In order to refer the values which you provide via [JMeter Properties](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005918945-JMeter-Properties-JMeter-Properties) section of the BlazeMeter load test configuration you need to use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) functions in your Test Plan like:

[image]

This way you will be able to [override the properties locally using `-J` command line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jhost=some-host -n -t test.jmx
```

and do the same using BlazeMeter's `Jmeter Properties` section.

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)